# Garbage Collector (GC) does not clean my ViewModel

Tags: wpf, garbage-collection

I have multiple instances of a certain viewmodel. This viewmodel has an object of a videoPlayer i created, and event handlers (propertychanged, etc).

I realized viewing the performance monitor that when i created new instances the private memory goes up. But then when i close that viewmodels (Removing the reference i have for them in other class) the memory is still high.

I did a heap memory dump to see why GC does not clean them and I see the event handlers. Well i did a method to unregister them and saw what happen to the memory heap, the viewmodels are still there but the event handler references dissapear. 
So i dont know what instances of viewModels are still there. 
From the Paths to Root option (where i saw the references to event handlers) now I only see cycled dependencies. What things i can search??
For other viewModels without the videoPLayer object when i remove the eventHandlers the GC clean them.

So i think that something happen with that object. Bu i don't see nothing in Path To Root.

Comment: Are you **disposing** them after you have removed all references?

Comment: Do you mean the videoPlayer object?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?